# How to get ChildPosition in ExpandableListView agaist every group

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have been spent almost two days to fix a bug but veined. Actually i want to select only one radiobutton in child group of every grouped item in expandablelistview. In this regard i am using this approach my adapter here here

```
public class AddToCartExpandable extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

Context context;
ArrayList<CartParentModel> ListTerbaru;
ArrayList<ArrayList<CartChildModel>> ListChildTerbaru;
private RadioButton lastCheckedRB = null;
private int selectedPosition = -1;
public static boolean FLAG_CHECKBOX;
private int selectedIndex = -1;
private int mSelectedVariation;

public AddToCartExpandable (Context context, 
ArrayList<CartParentModel>ListTerbaru, ArrayList<ArrayList<CartChildModel>> 
ListChildTerbaru){
    this.context=context;
    this.ListTerbaru=ListTerbaru;
    this.ListChildTerbaru=ListChildTerbaru;

}
@Override
public boolean areAllItemsEnabled()
{
    return true;
}


@Override
public CartChildModel getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return ListChildTerbaru.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}



@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean 
  isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final CartChildModel childTerbaru = getChild(groupPosition, 
    childPosition);

    AddToCartExpandable.ViewHolder holder= null;
    notifyDataSetChanged();

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) 
        context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = 
           infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item_add_to_cart_child, null);

        holder=new AddToCartExpandable.ViewHolder();
        holder.radio_btn_item_name=
        (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.radio_btn_item_name);
        holder.item_price_tv=
        (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_price_tv);

        holder.radio_btn = convertView.findViewById(R.id.radio_btn);
     //  holder.radio_btn_group = convertView.findViewById(R.id.radio_btn_group);
       holder.check_btn = convertView.findViewById(R.id.check_btn);


        if(FLAG_CHECKBOX){
            childTerbaru.setCheckRequired(false);
            holder.radio_btn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            holder.check_btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else {
            childTerbaru.setCheckRequired(true);
            holder.radio_btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.check_btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        holder.radio_btn_item_name.setText(childTerbaru.getChild_item_name());

    }
    else{
        holder=(AddToCartExpandable.ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }


    if(selectedIndex == childPosition)
    {
        holder.radio_btn.setChecked(true);
    }
    else
    {
        holder.radio_btn.setChecked(false);
    }
   /* if(childTerbaru.isCheckedddd()){
        holder.radio_btn.setChecked(true);
   //     holder.check_btn.setChecked(true);

    }
    else
    {
        holder.radio_btn.setChecked(false);
     //   holder.check_btn.setChecked(false);

    }*/

    if(childTerbaru.isCheckBoxIsChecked()){
        holder.check_btn.setChecked(true);
    }
    else {
        holder.check_btn.setChecked(false);
    }


    holder.item_price_tv.setText(childTerbaru.getChild_item_price());

    convertView.setTag(holder);
    return convertView;
}
@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return ListChildTerbaru.get(groupPosition).size();
}

@Override
public CartParentModel getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return ListTerbaru.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return ListTerbaru.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    CartParentModel terbaruModel = (CartParentModel) getGroup(groupPosition);
    AddToCartExpandable.ViewHolder holder= null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item_add_to_cart_parent, null);

        holder=new AddToCartExpandable.ViewHolder();
        holder.parent_tv=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.parent_tv);

        convertView.setTag(holder);

    }

    else{
        holder=(AddToCartExpandable.ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    String checkRequired = terbaruModel.getRequired();
    if (checkRequired.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {

        holder.parent_tv.setText(terbaruModel.getParentName() + " (Required)");
        FLAG_CHECKBOX = false;
    }
    else {
        holder.parent_tv.setText(terbaruModel.getParentName());
        FLAG_CHECKBOX = true;
    }


    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int arg0, int arg1) {
    return true;
}



static class ViewHolder{
    TextView parent_tv,radio_btn_item_name,item_price_tv;
    RadioButton radio_btn;
    CheckBox check_btn;
   RadioGroup radio_btn_group;
}

private void itemCheckChanged(View v) {
    selectedPosition = (Integer) v.getTag();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}


}

public void setSelectedIndex(int index)
{
    selectedIndex = index;
}
```

}

Also My Childclicklistner is here bellow

```
  cartExpandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new 
      ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView 
              expandableListView, View view, int groupPosition, int 
                      childPosition, long l) {

                                CartChildModel item = (CartChildModel) 
                          listAdapter.getChild(groupPosition,childPosition);

                                Toast.makeText(
                                        getApplicationContext(),
                                        item.getPos()
                                                + " : "
                                                , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                        .show();

                                boolean iteIsRequired = 
                                                    item.isCheckRequired();

                                if(!iteIsRequired) {

                                    CheckBox checkBox = 
                             view.findViewById(R.id.check_btn);

                                    if (checkBox != null) {
                                        checkBox.toggle();

                                        if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
                                            item.setCheckBoxIsChecked(true);

                           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                   item.getChild_item_name() + " checked" + "  
                 "+item.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        } else {

                   item.setCheckBoxIsChecked(false);

              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
              item.getChild_item_name() + " not checked", 
              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }

                                    }
                                }

                            else {

                                listAdapter.setSelectedIndex(groupPosition);
                                    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                                }



                                return false;
                            }
                        });
```

Moreover

```
CartChildModel item = (CartChildModel) listAdapter.getChild(groupPosition,childPosition);
```

this is the way how i am getting child position. now the problem is this Model class object did not give position in integer formate if this gives the position in integer then my problem can solve.

Comment: add your response please

Comment: Instead add only one child (Radiogroup with radiobuttons) to every group

Comment: Hi what do you mean by - Actually i want to select only one radiobutton in child group of every grouped item in expandablelistview

Comment: can you please fix it and code it for me

Comment: Hello @SanjayMajoka

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48560371/expandablelistview-add-groupradio-and-checkbox-in-child

This is the link where i post my design please take a look at that for betther understanding. I need to select one radiobutton checked in childgroup